# using dependency injection for Entity Framework 4.1 along with "Unit of Work" and "Repository" patterns

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have seen various implementations for Entity Framework using unit of work and repository patterns. ideally I want to use interfaces for unit of work, database context, repository (for both generic and specific repositories) and instantiate them in the BootStrapper code on application startup. Is this actually possible?

samples checked:

http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com (doesn't have any separate unit of work class, the database context itself implements IUnitOfwork)

http://efmvc.codeplex.com (uses a database factory to instantiate database context without utilising DI and database context does not implement interface)

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-Application-b01a9fe8 (instantiates database context and the repositories inside unit of work without any DI)

some implementations don't use any interface for database context and some instantiate database context and the repositories inside the UnitOfWork class and pass concrete context class in the constructor and some pass the interface for unit of work in the constructor for repository and it is totally confusing. Is there one best practice approach that allows DI and TDD when using Entity Framework 4.1? Is there a sample that demonstrates this?

Comment: just saw microsoftnlaperapp and felt to urge to post ayende's review.http://ayende.com/blog/19457/review-microsoft-n-layer-app-sample-part-i http://ayende.com/blog/27649/review-microsoft-n-layer-app-sample-part-iindash-getting-lost-in-the-architecture

Comment: yes, I have seen it. though there are some disagreements with the way it has been developed, there are still some things to learn from it (especially the accompanying guide). not sure why there isn't any answer to my question so far. may be it is too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I have next so far:

Declaration:

```
namespace Contracts // Contracts.dll
{
    public interface IUserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
namespace Data // Data.dll
{
    class UserRepository : Contracts.IUserRepository
    {
    }
}
```

IoC utility:

```
namespace Core // Core.dll
{
    public static class IoC
    {
        private static IUnityContainer _container = LoadContainer();

        private static IUnityContainer LoadContainer()
        {
            var unitySection = (Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
                new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(UserSettings.UnityContainerPath) },
                ConfigurationUserLevel.None).GetSection("unity");

            var container = new UnityContainer();
            unitySection.Configure(container);
            return container;
        }

        public static T Resolve<T>()
        {
            return _container.Resolve<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Unity.config:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
    </configSections>
    <unity>
        <containers>
            <container>
                <types>
                    <type type="Contracts.IUserRepository, Contracts" mapTo="Data.UserRepository, Data">
                        <lifetime type="singleton" />
                    </type>
                </types>
            </container>
        </containers>
    </unity>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can't find database context, unit of work pattern etc in this code. as I said, I need to be able to use interfaces for all these (for TDD) and inject the concrete types through config or fluent API.

Comment: @RKP: DbContext used in each declaration/implementation method

Comment: I'd recommend using the fluent configuration over XML. You're not going to change the implementation in production code, only for tests.

Comment: Your IoC class is a standard ServiceLocator. The ServiceLocator is considered an [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) in modern application architectures. And @TrueWill is right: use the fluent API instead of XML. Code is far less error-prone (IntelliSense, compiler support, etc.).Another really good article on Unit of Work with EF can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx).

Comment: @Sebastian: Yes, it is a service locator, but in opposite to described by Mark Seemann, my is automatically initialized at first use, so it doesn't suffers from the single problem raised in the article.

Comment: @SebastianWeber: though many seem to prefer Fluent Config, I think it suffers from one drawback. This config is normally defined in UI layer on application startup and since it needs to inject the concrete types for all interfaces, the UI project needs to have references to all other projects, which I am not sure is the right approach.

Comment: @abatishchev The ServiceLocator is an anti-pattern in itself no matter when you initialize it. It hides dependencies instead of making them plain obvious.

Comment: @RKP Every application I know of has a startup-project that needs to reference every dependency anyway. Just place a bootstrapper there and configure your container. If you need support for late-binding have a look at the [TecX project](http://tecx.codeplex.com). In the documentation section you find samples of loading configs at runtime.

Comment: @SebastianWeber: Looking pretty popular [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/KyleBurns/archive/2012/04/27/dependency-injection-vs.-service-locator.aspx) not voiding Service Locator pattern immediately but comparing pros and cons Constructor Dependency Injection vs. Service Locator. Obviously both pros and cons have both patterns.